# how to find circuit breaker for exterior light

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Most breaker finders seem to work with outlets, but I have 3 exterior light fixtures which are on all the time. I want to find the circuit so I can work on this and fix it.

Comment: You can always try 1 breaker at a time, or purchase a circuit breaker finder and a light socket adapter. Most lighting circuits have a switch some place.

Comment: The fixtures are 4 pin cfl's probably G24Q base. If I could find and outlet that could hook up to that, then maybe I could use a ordinary breaker finder. I still have to figure out if it is a 120 v circuit, or 277. Each light is controlled by its own  photo cell. It is odd that all three would go at the same time. This is for a small commercial building, still, there are hundreds of circuits and breakers. I have flipped all lighting breakers, at least what is listed.

Comment: For commercial work I use a greenlee cs8000 it will trace through conduit and is one of the most accurate out there, to figure out which panel measure the voltage if 120 it won't be in the 277 panel or visa versa. Then there is the old school of following the conduit bact to the panel. If 277v a residential circuit finder won't work. So it sounds like a voltage measurement is needed. There are 120-277v g24q lamps out there.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I think I will go old school and get a help we and flip every flipping breaker until I find it.  These lights aren't on the drawings and must have been added after construction, and nope, they  never did label where it was tied into.

Comment: That sounds like work.  Are you sure you don't want to just [buy the tester](https://www.menards.com/main/electrical/electrical-tools-accessories/electrical-testers/greenlee-reg-cs-8000-circuit-seeker-circuit-tracer/cs-8000/p-1444431695575.htm), *how much could it cost?* LOL no seriously, the trick is turn off half the breakers and see if it goes out.  You now know which half of the panel it is.  Turn off half of those.  Now you know which 1/4 panel it is.   In a 32-switch panel, you'll get there in 5.

Comment: Holy cow those have gone up but I would purchase again especially trying to trace industrial circuits through huge gutters, conduits and through walls. Where you can't just flip the breakers or have a fault mid way this thing will find it.

Answer (score 5):

### Turn off half the panel

And go see if the light is still on.  *You now know which half of the panel it is.*

Turn off half *those* breakers.   You now know which quarter of the panel it is.

*Note that you do not need to see the light go out.  If it remains on, that tells you it's in the "unturned off" half of the breakers you are testing*.

Now turn off half of the quarter.  Still on? That means it's in the half of the quarter (1/8)  you did not turn off.  Divide that in two (1/16) and go again.

You should be able to get there in five, maybe six on a big panel.

Comment: I agree with the half split rule the only problem at this point we don't know if it's the low voltage or high voltage service panel. But 1/2 split saves time.

Answer (score 2):

Old school...

Get a cheap little light socket adapter that gives you a plug outlet and plug in a portable radio. That way you can turn it up loud and hear if it is working or not from where you are flipping the breakers on and off. If you don't get radio reception, use a boom box / CD player. 
[image]

Comment: It's a CFL G24Q base not an Edison, but he can check to see if the lamp goes out.

Comment: you can also plug an extension cord to the socket adapter and run it back to the breaker panel .... plug  in a lamp ....... or you can turn off all the breakers including the main breaker .... then use a multimeter to measure the resistance between the end of the extension cord and each of the breakers

Comment: Thank you every one for helping with this. I did find the circuit when I flipped the breaker for the emergency light circuit, which I overlooked before. The lights are now listed on the drawings, and on the load center.